# Обратное геокодирование без отображения карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Могу ли я использовать обратное геокодирование яндекса не отображая его результаты на карте?
В условиях использование, конечно, написано, что это необходимо. Но что если мне действительно нет надобности в отображении данных, которые я получил?
Данные, полученные при обратном геокодировании необходимы для получения региона, в котором находится пользователь и последующего выведения его в начало списка.

Comment: С подобными вопросами лучше в техподдержку Яндекса

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [условиям использования](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) API Яндекс.Карт геокодирование с бесплатным ключом без отображения результатов на общедоступной карте запрещено.

Вы можете использовать код на открытой странице с отображением данных на карте, обеспечивая небольшую рекламу компании либо приобрести коммерческий ключ и спокойно делать это в своей закрытой системе, либо на странице без карты.

Младшая линейка тарифов начинается от 1500р/месяц за 300 запросов в сутки: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/tariffs/doc/jsapi/prices/index-docpage/